# C#/powershell encoding digital signature to base 64 and decoding it back and authenticating it.

Tags: c#, powershell, encoding, base64, digital-signature

Hi I am trying to stuff a digital signature inside the Authorization header of a POST request.

I need to use powershell by requirement, but the actual digital signature is done in a c# class which I call from inside of my powershell.

`$obj = new-object DigitalSignatureApplication.DigitalSignature 
$signature = $obj.GetSignature($certificateName,$Message)`

Same with the authentication part

```
$verification = $obj.verifySignature($signature64,$certificateName,$Message)
```

The idea is to Base 64 encode the signature in powershell and send it across in the POST request and then decode it back and authenticate the signature.

```
$signatureBytes  = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($signature)
$signature64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($signatureBytes)
$headers = @{Authorization = "DSignature "+$signature64}
```

The problem is that between encoding it to base64 and decoding it back, something is messing up the signature and the authentication fails, I have tried encoding and decoding purely in c# too but even that dose not work.

The following is my signing logic in C#

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(UnsignedMessage);
byte[] signature = privateKey.SignData(buffer, new SHA1Managed());

 return EncodeTo64(GetString(signature)); // converting to base 64 before returning
// return GetString(signature); // just converting the byte [] to a string
```

This is my verification/ authentication logic in C#

```
 byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
 string decodedSigneture = DecodeFrom64(encodedsignature);
 byte[] signaturebytes = GetBytes(decodedSigneture);
 bool verify = publicKey.VerifyData(buffer, new SHA1Managed(), signaturebytes);
```

The following is my logic for Get string and get bytes.

```
 static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}

static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
    char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
    return new string(chars);
}
```

The following is the two different ways of encoding and decoding to base 64 processes I have tried ....

```
        public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
        {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }
        public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
        {
            var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
        }
        static public string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
        {
            byte[] toEncodeAsBytes
                  = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
            string returnValue
                  = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
            return returnValue;
        }

        static public string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
        {
            byte[] encodedDataAsBytes
                = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
            string returnValue =
               System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
            return returnValue;
        }
```

Thanks in advance,